# Загрузить картинку с сайта

Tags: поддержка, редактор, загрузка-изображения

В старом интерфейсе была загрузка картинки по ссылке из интернета, а в новом что-то не вижу:

[image: скриншот]

Comment: Ни разу не пользовался, но вот [тут](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/317590/339911) есть инфа. И даже [ответ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/317579/339911) как это сделать.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Порядок действий необходимый для вставки изображения со стороннего сайта:

**Вариант №1:**

1. Вызовите контекстное меню и выберите пункт "Копировать картинку":

   [image: Копировать картинку]
2. Откройте форму формирования сообщения > вызовите
   контекстное меню > выберите пункт "Вставить" (Ctrl + V):

   [image: Вставить]
3. Следующий и завершающий этап. Нажимаем кнопку "Добавить картинку" и
   дожидаемся загрузки изображения:

   [image: Добавить картинку]

---

**Вариант №2**

1. Копируем ссылку на изображение

   [image: Ссылка]
2. В форме формирования сообщения нажимаем на иконку с изображением (Ctrl + G):

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
3. Нажимаем клавиши Ctrl + V, это позволит вставить ссылку на изображение

   [image: Ctrl + V изображения]

Comment: Работает! Хотя, в первом варианте первый пункт вроде лишний.